# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupted

Tags: c#

I am working on a Project which works fine while i was using .NET Framework 3.5 but later I used Framework 4.0. It was working fine. But however sometime I got following error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." I even try to catch Exception using try catch but still it didn't catch the exception. I am not sure why this is happening. Is there any problem in FrameWork 4.0? Can any one suggest me. I try different things like

1. Tools menu ->Options -> Debugging -> General -> Uncheck this option "Suppress JIT optimization on module load"
2. Download Hotfixes of microsoft for .Net Framework 4.0 and so on. But still I couldn't resolved this issue.. Can some one suggest

---

```
protected override bool ConcreteExecute()
{
    using (BusinessLogic.GUI.VersionsForm dlg = new BusinessLogic.GUI.VersionsForm(_infoItems[0]))
    {
        try
        {
            dlg.ShowDialog(); <= AccessViolation Exception comes from here but didn't catch
        }
        catch (AccessViolationException ex)
        {

        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you use somewhere pointer access (unsafe code) in your dialog ?

Comment: Is your VersionsForm using any unmanaged/unsafe code?

Comment: The answer lies in the code you did not show us.

Comment: Show all of your code that involves pointers and/or P/Invoke definitions. The problem is likely to be centered there. You can't catch this exception, and it has nothing to do with the JITter. It's a bug in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably somewhere in your `VersionsForm` dialog, in a method or event handler called by `ShowDialog`. Try putting breakpoints in the `VersionsForm` code and see if you can pinpoint where the error occurs.

To even get an AccessViolation exception there has to bee some unmanaged or unsafe code involved. Pure managed code can't generate it, so you should focus on putting breakpoints in those places where unmanaged code is used - or external unmanaged code is called.

Comment: Hi, even i used breakpoint I couldn't catch that error. Even when i used try catch in that block it didn't catch the error. However I believed the problem could be because of using some unmanaged code. How can i detect or check those external unmanaged code in my code ??

Comment: Is It because I am using interface ICloneable where above the interface it is written

Comment: #region Assembly mscorlib.dll, v2.0.50727
// C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll
#endregion